# How can I redirect the saved URL in NFC tag to another URL which I will control from my react-native app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redirect, nfc, url-parameters

Well, here's the scenario... I have developed a react-native app. In a certain page I put the functionality to scan and write a certain URL in the NFC tag. Now if anybody scans that they can get the URL and thus the webpage.

Now I will leave the NFC tag anywhere and I want to redirect that saved URL on the NFC tag to another URL or page and I want to control this functionality from my react-app without even overwriting the NFC tag again. From far I want to redirect that saved URL on NFC tag to another URL if that make sense...what do I need to do?

I have created the website for that URL already. Which of the sides do I need to code, my website side or my react-native app side?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to show us some code.